# PHP Shopping Cart Quantity Update using Session without database

Tags: php, session-variables, shopping-cart

I want to update my quantities on textbox.  What I did in the first place is that I added the quantity + textbox. I'm getting an error:

> "Undefined indexed: txtquant"

Here is my code:

NOTE: There has to be no mysql database because it is not part of this project: only session variables.

Here is my updated href code which will update the textbox and quantity. Also, this belongs to the session variable:

```
if(isset($_GET["updates"])) {
    $i = $_GET["updates"];
    $qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$i] + 1;    
    $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = $amounts[$i] * $_GET['txtquant'];
    $_SESSION["cart"][$i] = $i;
    $_SESSION["qty"][$i] = $qty;  
}
```

Here is my code from which the update holds the href and the quantity and the cart:

```
 <?php
     $total = 0;
     foreach ( $_SESSION["cart"] as $i ) {
     ?>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo( $products[$_SESSION["cart"][$i]] ); ?></td>
     <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
     <td><?php echo ( $_SESSION["qty"][$i]); ?></td>
     <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
     <td><?php echo( $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] ); ?></td>
     <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>

     <td><a href="?delete=<?php echo($i); ?>">Delete from cart</a>
     </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txtquants" value="1"><a href="?
     updates=<?php echo($i); ?>">Update Cart</a></td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: anyone can help ?

Comment: Which line says that?

Comment: line 3 sir here:$_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = $amounts[$i] * $_GET['txtquant'];

Comment: That line is nowhere on your code snippet.

Comment: Ill edit it sir please wait thank you

Comment: Edit is complete sir please help me thank you ..

Comment: You are not sending that value in this line `<a href="?
     updates=<?php echo($i); ?>">Update Cart</a>`

Comment: how sir? the href works fine although what I need is the value of the textbox which is 'txtquant' doesn't send its value to the quantity to update that is my problem sir.

Comment: If you want to send another value, then you need to add it: `<a href="?updates=<?php echo $i  ?>&txtquant=1">Update Cart</a>`

Comment: Does not work sir :( I've been frustrated with this.. any other solution?

Comment: I think the problem is on the isset update please help sir.

Comment: what i need is to sums upp txtquant and quantity for e.g --- QTY is 1 and the Textbox you input is 10 then the result will be 11

Comment: you have to provide a valid data its not making sence here create a php fiddle if you can

Comment: i will be glad to solve your problem

Comment: Okay sir please wait